# Angular Karma Writing unit tests for get method_name returns 'method_name' is not a function

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

My ts code is as follows,

```
 private _state: State = {
    page: 1,
    pageSize: 4,
    searchTerm: '',
    sortColumn: '',
    sortDirection: ''
  };
      get page() { return this._state.page; }
      get pageSize() { return this._state.pageSize; }
      get searchTerm() { return this._state.searchTerm; }
```

When I wrote the tests,

```
it('searchTerm()', () => {
        (component as any)._state = {
            page: 1,
            pageSize: 4,
            searchTerm: '',
            sortColumn: '',
            sortDirection: ''
          };
        let result = (component as any).searchTerm();
        expect(result).toEqual('');
    });
```

It returns the below error,
Chrome 101.0.4951.67 (Windows 10) NgbdTableComplete searchTerm() FAILED
TypeError: component.searchTerm is not a function
at UserContext. (src/app/ngbd-table-complete/ngbd-table-complete.spec.ts:78:41)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:372:1)
at ProxyZoneSpec.push.QpwO.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (vendor.js:62723:43)
at ZoneDelegate.invoke (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:371:1)
at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-evergreen.js:134:1)
at runInTestZone (vendor.js:63003:38)
at UserContext. (vendor.js:63018:24)
at

Comment: Can you try to access it like a property instead? Remove the `()` and see how that goes.

Comment: Remove the () works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like that should be accessed like an actual property, without the parentheses `()`. You can find more info about such getters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).